# BLE device scanning in background using CoreBluetooth swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth, ibeacon

I have an app demanding to scan BLE devices around in background mode when app is not active in foreground.
I have implemented such functionality using `CoreBluetooth` framework. This is code, I am using to scan device. First I have all device in DB, fetch and creating `array`.

```
for item in self.allItems ?? [] {
    let uuid = UUID(uuidString: item.identifier)!
    let id = CBUUID(nsuuid: uuid)
    self.allServiceIds.append(id)
}
```

And when start scanning, passing same array in method.

```
self.centralManager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: self.allServiceIds, options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey:true])
```

Also I have tried to pass service ids in array as I read lots of articles suggesting in background mode it is required.

Also inside `Capabilities`, I have checked required options. But still it is not scanning in when app is in background.

[image: Signing & Capabilities]

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: You can’t use the duplicates key in the background. You can create your CBUUID directly from a String. Are you sure that you are scanning for the the service your peripheral is advertising?  Try the LightBlue app to confirm

Comment: In LightBlue, I am getting error while click on found device. @Paulw11

Comment: As per suggestion, directly creating `CBUUID`, `let id = CBUUID(string: item.identifier)`

Comment: Also remove duplicate key option from method call, `self.centralManager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: self.allServiceIds, options: nil)`, but still not working.

Comment: Since you said it is working in the foreground, what does "not working in the background" mean?  What, specifically, does not happen when your app is in the background?  What series of steps are you performing in terms of launching your app, moving it to the background and turning on your peripheral?

Answer (score 0):

A few tips:

1. **Get your app working in the foreground first.**  Only once this is working should you try to get it working in the background.
2. Make sure that **bluetooth is turned on** in phone settings.
3. Make sure you have obtained **Bluetooth permission** from the user.   An iPhone will send a dialog to prompt you for this permission the first time an app runs (it is triggered by `CBCentralManager` usage.)  If you deny this permission, you won't see the dialog again and you must go to Settings -> Your App -> Permissions -> Bluetooth to enable it manually.
4. Take care that you have **set the CBCentralManagerDelegate properly** and that you are getting callbacks.  In particular, log the callback to `centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager)` and make sure that you see `central.state` transition to `.poweredOn`.  Only once you reach the `poweredOn` state should you start scanning. See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanagerdelegate/1518888-centralmanagerdidupdatestate
5. Start off testing in the foreground **without filtering** `self.centralManager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey:true])` (note the `withServices: nil`). Only once you get callbacks detecting peripherals should you start filtering for specific service UUIDs. This will help you eliminate all other problems before filtering on the service.

If you can get all of the above working, there are tricks you can do to get duplicate detections even in the background.

If you cannot get the above working, please described the results of the above, and show more of your code including where you instantiate the `CBCentralManager`, where you set the delegate, showing the delegate callback methods, and describing which delegate callbacks get called and when.

Comment: In foreground it is working fine and as expected. I did exactly what you have written in steps 1 to 5. Now I wanted to make it working in background. and that is somehow not working. @davidgyoung

Comment: Does your code work in the foreground with the services element populated with a non-nil value here?  `self.centralManager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey:true])`

Comment: Yeah, I am getting peripheral. @davidgyoung

Comment: Are you using a dedicated BLE peripheral or a a second iOS device programmed to act as a BLE Peripheral?

Comment: I am using dedicated peripheral device.